# How I web-scrape the data a website that I need perform some action in website before the data I need via Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, web-scraping

[The website that I would like to scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBchi.png)

Before scraping the data I need first I must choose departure, arrival and date then I must clicked the green buton then I can reach the data I would like to scrape.

How I can perform these actions in website via Flutter. Then I will use these datas in the Flutter app.

I tried to scrape via import http.dart and parser.dart libraries but I couldn't. I am beginner in coding and Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Hey found a article which will help you do this.

Follow :

##### https://morioh.com/p/b7b4aa4d696e

Kudos to Morioh for the detailed step by step article.

##### Concern : this might be outdated package as there is no update since past one year.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe need the `dart:html` in all app scope , but this file are limited on the web (or You need to do something different on the web than on an Android device!).

you can create 3 file and to handle this mode.

file `web.dart` :

```
import 'dart:html' as html;

void webScrap() {
  // blablabla webScrap in web
}


String cookie = "";
```

file `native.dart` :

```
void webScrap() {
  // blablabla webScrap in native
}

String cookie = "";
```

file `switch_native_web.dart` :

```
import 'native.dart' if (dart.library.html) 'web.dart' as switch_value;

class SwitchNativeWeb {

  static String cookie = switch_value.cookie;

  static void webScrap() {
    switch_value.webScrap();
  }
}
```

But i suggest to you , see this example for web scraping in flutter .

Gist full Snippets: [Gist.Github.com](https://gist.github.com/esmaeil-ahmadipour/ed69de5e7f19dfb9ae87bd79c8012008)

Repository : [Github.com](https://github.com/esmaeil-ahmadipour/Flutter_Web_Scraper)